# How mixed percentage bars should be?

Tags: progress-bar

By mixed percentage bars, I mean something like the "likes bar" in youtube, with a left percentage bar, a right percentage bar, and maybe a separator:

[image]

Should they be like:

[       70%       ] || [   30%    ]

(But the whole bar would be more than 100%)

or:

[      68,7%      ||  28,9%   ]

(so that the whole bar is 100%)

or:

[      70%      ||] [  30%   ]

with the separator that takes a little space of one of the side?

Comment: They should be as mixed as the percentages allow... I dont really understand this question

Answer (score 11):

It doesn't really matter. People can't tell 1-pixel distances easily.

If it's just 2 elements, then add the divider to the length.

If it's more than 2, don't use a divider and make sure you use colors that don't mix.

Answer (score 1):

The CENTER of the separator should be calculated to be in the exact ratio position, rounded to the nearest pixel.

You can easily tell the centerline of a thick line from its width, and the center of something, most will agree, is where something "actually is", specially in this case where a thick line is just a concrete visual implementation of an imaginary line with no thickness separating two rectangles.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Aadaam that a small number of pixels will not be noticed, so any of the options would be fine as long as the separator is narrow (say, 1-5 pixels).

That said, the important thing to keep in mind is that you're trying to represent a *ratio*, so you want the *ratio* of the red and green sections to be close to the actual ratio (70:30). Therefore, I would actually go with your first option (which allows the overall length to be longer than 100%):

```
[       70%       ] || [   30%    ]
```